# Why cant Perl find my Curl library?

Tags: yum, perl, curl, make

I created a new module using **h2xs** which built a module tree for me and a bunch of files.

Git as far as running make test but then make failed saying it couldnt find WWW::Curl, but I had installed Curl with Yum so I'm not sure why this is a problem!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;
use WWW::Curl;
```

Make Error:

```
 Error:  Can't locate WWW/Curl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: dir .. dir...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Active Perl and so I had to install with Active Perl's repository command and not yum!

Answer (score 0):

Perl may have been compiled with certain directories in @INC that is not where curl was installed.  Try find / -type f -iname Curl.pm (using iname in case the capitalized C in curl turns out to be the problem) and then run your script with -I /path/to/Curl.pm and see if that works.

If so, follow this helpful post to get that resolved:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-per